# How to simplify multiple CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several similar CTE, actually 9. The difference is in the `WHERE` clause from the subquery on the column `for`.

```
WITH my_cte_1 AS (
    SELECT  id,
        "time",
        LEAD("time",1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY id,"time"
        ) next_time
    FROM history
    where id IN (SELECT id FROM req WHERE type = 'sup' AND for = 1)
),
WITH my_cte_2 AS (
            SELECT  id,
        "time",
        LEAD("time",1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY id,"time"
        ) next_time
    FROM history
    where id IN (SELECT id FROM req WHERE type = 'sup' AND for = 2)
),
WITH my_cte_3 AS (
            SELECT  id,
        "time",
        LEAD("time",1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY id,"time"
        ) next_time
    FROM history
    where id IN (SELECT id FROM req WHERE type = 'sup' AND for = 3)
) 

SELECT
'History' AS "Indic",
(SELECT count(DISTINCT(id)) FROM my_cte_1 ) AS "cte1",
(SELECT count(DISTINCT(id)) FROM my_cte_2 ) AS "cte2",
(SELECT count(DISTINCT(id)) FROM my_cte_3 ) AS "cte3",
```

My database is read only so I can't use function.

Each CTE process a large record of data.

Is there a way, where I can setup a parameter for the column `for` or a workaround ?

Comment: Can you show what's done in the final query (after all the CTEs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming a little bit here, but I would think something like this would work:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT
      h.id, h."time",
      LEAD(h."time",1) OVER (PARTITION BY h.id ORDER BY h.id, h."time") next_time,
      r.for
    FROM
      history h
      join req r on
        r.type = 'sup' and
        h.id = r.id and
        r.for between 1 and 3
)
select
  'History' AS "Indic",
  count (distinct id) filter (where for = 1) as cte1,
  count (distinct id) filter (where for = 2) as cte2,
  count (distinct id) filter (where for = 3) as cte3
from cte
```

This would avoid multiple passes on the various tables and should run much quicker unless these are highly selective values.

Another note...  the "lead" analytic function doesn't appear to be used.  If this is really all there is to your query, you can omit that and make it run a lot faster.  I left it in assuming it had some other purpose.